# Changing adjacent elements on hover css

Tags: html, css

Please tell me why when you hover over the third `div`, the size of the second `div` does not change, as when you hover over the first `div`.

```css
#block {
width: 50%;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 10%;
  background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
  background: green;
}
div:nth-child(1):hover {
    width: 80%;
}
div:nth-child(1):hover + div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 10%; 
}
div:nth-child(3):hover {
    width: 80%;
}
div:nth-child(3):hover + div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 10%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
<div class="div">1</div>
<div class="div">2</div>
<div class="div">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Mozilla Developers Website For More info Check the link at the bottom

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and
> matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first
> element, and both are children of the same parent element.

This means it will try to find a sibling of the same parent that is after the current selecting element not the sibling before the current One.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator